# git know what commit number my branch is on

Tags: git, github, git-svn

In Git how can I know what commit number is my branch on?

Git status just shows the difference between the files

```
  git status
```

I want to know the commit number my branch is on

Comment: Are you talking about a revision number similar to svn? Because such numbers don't exist in git. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `git log -1` though you could use `git rev-parse HEAD`

Comment: @meWantToLearn: no, it won't apply any changes. It only displays the current commit or shows the commit hash of it.

Comment: thanks. Wish it had commands like mercurial hg incoming to know the incoming changes.

Comment: @meWantToLearn it does. do a `git fetch` and then diff the HEAD.  suggest trying https://github.com/Gazler/githug